# save json object to string has some unwanted character

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I try to save json object to a file, Here, I have two problem.

The **first** one is "How can I get success or error status, that represents for writing the json data.

Below is my Code:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'json.php',
                type: "POST",  // type should be POST
                data: {
                    json: JSON.stringify(jsonData),

                    name: workerId+".json"
                }, // send the string directly
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response['status']);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.status);
                }
            });
```

`json.php:`

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: application/json");
   $json = $_POST['json'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $info = json_encode($json);
   $file = fopen($name,'w+');
   fwrite($file, $info);
   fclose($file);
?>
```

The **second** one is:
I find my final output.json file has some unwanted character like `\"`

```
"{\"compartments\":[{\"id\":0,\"type\":\"M\",\"name\":\"cytosol\",\"x\":0.0734694,\"y\":0.36478122582308947,\"w\":0.646259,\"h\":1,\"children\":{\"complexs\":[{\"id\":8,\"type\":\"C\",\"x\":0.4442110000000001,\"y\":0.537736,\"w\":0.0252632,\"h\":0.0188679}......
```

Howerver, when I use console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData)); I find the result is exactly what I want.

```
{"compartments":[{"id":0,"type":"M","name":"cytosol","x":0.0734694,"y":0.36478122582308947,"w":0.646259,"h":1,"children":{"complexs":[{"id":8,"type":"C","x":0.4442110000000001,"y":0.537736,"w":0.0252632, .....
```

So How can I solve this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data you are getting from `$_POST['json']` is already in json format. PHP is getting it as a string. By calling json_encode on it again, you are just json_encode'ing a string, not the json data as it is never parsed by the server. This is causing php to quote the string and escape any existing quotes. Since you are already getting json, you don't need the json_encode line or you could json_parse `$_POST['json']` and then json_encode it again. Your choice. The first option is likely better.

Comment: The error and success are more for the ajax call, not the status of the php script. Error will fire if there was an error loading the page such as not found or permission denied. Success will fire if the page loaded successfully. This includes if there was a php error, typically the error will be output as standard html/text which is a valid response as far as ajax goes. You could always echo out a status in php, which will be the argument passed into the success function and based on that response determine success/fail.

Answer (score 0):

You're encoding the data twice. First, in Javascript:

```
json: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
```

then, again, in PHP:

```
$info = json_encode($json);
```

The result you're seeing is the encoded version of the already-encoded string.  Remove the `json_encode()` call in PHP:

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$file = fopen($name,'w+');
if (fwrite($file, $json) === false)
{
  // something went wrong
}
fclose($file);
```

Note that we tested the result of `fwrite()` to see if it was successful.

Comment: Thanks, You are right! How can I get success or error status? My status return 200

Comment: What would you expect it to return? If you want something other than `200`, you'll need to send it yourself. In recent versions of PHP, you'd use [`http_response_code`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php). See that page for examples, and for a substitute you can use in older versions of PHP.